# Parsing data to lists of lists

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing

I am running into problems when trying to parse data to a list of lists.
I am trying to scrape information about departments and their subjects.
However, as there are different numbers of subjects in each department I need to create a list of lists so that I may later link the data together. I have managed to navigate the index error and the problem seems to come from compiling the subject list.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('URL')

page_source_code = html.fromstring(page.text)


departments_list = []
subject_list = []

for dep in range(1,3):
    departments = page_source_code.xpath('tag'
                                         +str(dep)+']tag/text()')

    ### print(dep, departments)
    if departments == []:
        pass
    else:
        departments_list.append(departments[0])


    for sub in range(1,20):
        subjects = page_source_code.xpath('tag'
                                      +str(dep)+']tag'
                                      +str(sub)+']tag/text()')
        ### print(sub, subjects)
        if subjects == []:
            pass
        else:
            subject_list.append(subjects[0])

print('Department list ------ ', len(departments_list), departments_list, '\n')
print('Subject list ------ ', len(subject_list), subject_list)
```

My output looks like this:

```
Department list ------  2 ['Department_1', 'Department_2'] 

Subject list ------  7 ['Subject_1'(dep_1), 'Subject_2 '(dep_1), 'Subject_3 '(dep_1), 'Subject_4'(dep_1), 'Subject_5'(dep_2), 'Subject_6 '(dep_2), 'Subject_7 '(dep_2)']
```

This code seems to put all subjects into one list. I would like it as follows:

```
Subject list ------  7 [['Subject_1'(dep_1), 'Subject_2 '(dep_1), 'Subject_3 '(dep_1), 'Subject_4'(dep_1)], ['Subject_5'(dep_2), 'Subject_6 '(dep_2), 'Subject_7 '(dep_2)']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two add the two list globally for subject list 
and find out the 'dep_1' or 'dep_2' word in subjects[0] string.

```
     #declare the list for subject 
     sub_list1 = [] sub_list2 = []

     #this code is under the second for loop
     if subjects.find('dep_1') == -1 :
         sub_list2.append(subjects[0])
     else:
         sub_list1.append(subjects[0])

     #Please remove the subjectList.append statement 
     #from second for loop
     #and put it end of both loop like that .
     subjectList = [sub_list1,sub_list2]
```